# Parsing a hexadecimal string to base 10 long integer

Tags: c#, python, hex

I need to parse a hexadecimal value to base 10 long integer. Value is something like:

```
 9F2EEA4AA03D55B33172E9A86CFF6156AC1628C67983193A337B98995151F9B0F41562290DB98697280E805803E4B18914519CEB55CEA5D03A927C28C36A4BC7
```

How can i do this?

UPDATE:

In python, i used following:

```
>> num = "9F2EEA4AA03D55B33172E9A86CFF6156AC1628C67983193A337B98995151F9B0F41562290DB98697280E805803E4B18914519CEB55CEA5D03A927C28C36A4BC7"
>> int(num, 16)
>> 8337103942674051648235321365669510487642415361796636721089378763661406518267124809778145800381557738780272231500412167743930433352841689114003303823985607L
```

when my colleague tries @Sergey's answer,  my colleague get a different result (a negative value while mine is not a negative one)

```
>> BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(num, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
>> -5070703987268545451338703632536335639836950458795756656634182680060357511806422167023728497785345688909759626686073883109823449459104880832430345182098489
```

Comment: How about looping through 2 characters at a time and shifting in the result.

Comment: I am a python developer and i can easily do this in python. My colleague (who uses C#) needs that. And could not find a solution to overcome this.

Comment: Since BigInteger deals with signed numbers, can you just prepend the hex string with zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [BigInteger Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) to work with large integers.

```
BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("0D574F480A03D55B33172E9A86CFF6156AC1628C67983193A337B98995151F9B0F41562290DB98697280E805803E4B18914519CEB55CEA5D03A927C28C36A4BC7", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string s = bigInteger.ToString(); // String with decimal representation.
```

## Update

Prepend (start) the string with 0 if the number should be **interpreted as positive** even if its first character is 8–F. See the example above: `0D574...`

Comment: @FallenAngel, see the updated answer - start the string with `0`.